# failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-container

I am new to Docker and i am trying to create an image from my application, i created `Dockerfile` in the same directory with `package.json` file with no extension, just `Dockerfile`

Now in `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:14.16.0
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

and i am trying to build the image with that command

```
docker build -t app .
```

But i got this constant error:

```
[+] Building 0.2s (2/2) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                           0.2s 
 => => transferring dockerfile: 2B                                                                             0.0s 
 => CANCELED [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                     0.0s 
 => => transferring context:                                                                                   0.0s
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount457647683/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
```

My folder directory is like this:

```
   |- Dockerfile
   |- README.md
   |- src
   |- package.json
   |- public
   |- node-modules
   |-package-lock.json
```

My **OS** is : **Windows 10 Pro**

Comment: it works now but i don't know how this happened, i guess i used the docker build command in the wrong directory, i am running the commands from vscode terminals so i guess i didn't run the command in the root directory of the project and where the dockerfile exist, make sure you are in the correct place to run your commands
@MarcinWolny

Answer (score 22):

I encountered a different issue, so sharing as an FYI.  On Windows, I created the docker file as `DockerFile` instead of `Dockerfile`. The capital `F` messed things up.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30833081)

Comment: Not only DockerFile to Dockerfile... check the extension even "yml" & "yaml" doesnt support

Comment: This definitely answers the question I had and search engine directed me to this page.  I used the F and got the same error as the OP.

Answer (score 20):

Double check that you are in the right directory.
I was in downloads/app

When I downloaded the app from Docker as part of their tutorial, I extracted it and it ended up in downloads/app**/app**
Type `dir` in your terminal to see if you can see dockerfile or another folder called app.

Comment: I literally facepalmed myself because indeed I was in the wrong directory

Comment: In my case I didn't notice that IntelliJ created the project in a subfolder instead of using the supplied directory. So it ended up being in `../project-name/project-name` instead of `../project-name`

Answer (score 6):

If you come here from a duplicate, notice also that Docker prevents you from accessing files outside the current directory tree. So, for example,

```
docker build -f ../Dockerfile .
```

will not be allowed. You have to copy the Dockerfile into the current directory, or perhaps run the build in the parent directory.

For what it's worth, you also can't use symlinks to files elsewhere in your file system from `docker build` for security reasons.

Answer (score 5):

Naming convention for Docker file is 'Dockerfile' not 'DockerFile', I got this error because of this.

Comment: Isn't this a copy of previous answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70733833/593045?

Answer (score 1):

It's a pretty generic error message but what caused it for me, was in my Dockerfile, I didn't have a space specifying the initial command properly. Here's how it should look like:

```
CMD ["command-name"]
```

Notice the space between "CMD" and "[".

Instead, my mistake was that I typed `CMD["command-name"]` which resulted in the error you described.

Answer (score 0):

In windows when the Dockerfile is in .txt format I got this error. changing it to type "file" fixed the issue.

Comment: I guess you are trying to say you named it `Dockerfile.txt` instead of `Dockerfile`. You could still get away with that if you said `docker build -f Dockerfile.txt .`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error was that the Dockerfile location was incorrect so I correct the location and it worked

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What **exactly** did you do to resolve the problem? What makes you think that this relates to the initial problem?